# How to count the occurrences of each word in a column in R?

Tags: r, text, rstudio

I have a data set of a text analysis. There's a column that shows if one of predefined terms is recognized (shows the term itself). looks somewhat like this (relevant column is "funnel_term"):

[sample of my data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDeL2.png)

I want to count how many times each of the terms in the "funnel_term" appears. thought of a for loop but it's not working as I wished. the output I'm looking for would be something like that:

sexual - 6

racist - 4

ill - 2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of sharing a screenshot of your data, please use `dput` to share an excerpt of it. That way, we can be sure we're testing solutions against your precise problem. And for general guidance on the importance of including minimal, reproducible examples in your questions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `your_data %>% count(funnel_term)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep()` for this. Example with minimal data set:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("['Sexual']", "['Sexual']"))

length(grep("Sexual", df$x))
```

Or with a prettier output:

```
paste("Sexual - ", length(grep("Sexual", test$x)), sep="")

[1] "Sexual - 2"
```

Or with the package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x = c("['Sexual']", "['Sexual']"))
df %>% dplyr::count(x)
```

This doesn't work for cells with two words, for example `"['Sexual', 'Religion']"`. So we need this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x = c("['Sexual', 'Religion']", "['Sexual']"))

df %>% mutate(x2 = strsplit(as.character(x), ",")) %>% 
  unnest(x2) %>% 
  mutate(x2 = str_replace_all(x2, "[^[:alnum:]]", "")) %>% 
  count(x2)
```

Comment: thank you, the thing is, I want it to go over all the words in "funnel_terms".
each time it would take a word and then count it's occurrences. then go to the next word at that column and do the same. without having to predefine the word it's looking for.

Comment: The `dplyr` version essentially does that, although it doesn't count individual words  if you have cases like `"['Sexual', 'Sexual']"`. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to count multiple occurrences of words like `"racist"` within a row? If so, you may want to check out the function `gregexpr`:

```
gregexpr("sexual", df$text)
```

This will tell you the starting points of each of the words `"racist"` in your column. To get a count of all of them, you can do:

```
object_1 <- gregexpr("sexual", df$text)

for (i in seq_len(length(object_1))) {
  if (object_1[[i]] == -1) {
    object_1[[i]] <- NULL
  }
}

sum(sapply(object_1, function (x) {
  length(x)
}))
```

If you want to find words like `"sexual"` but not words like `"asexual"` or `"sexually"`, you should use regular expressions. Use

```
gregexpr("\\bsexual\\b", df$text)
```

instead of

```
gregexpr("sexual", df$text)
```

To get your desired output, you would do:

```
original_funnel_terms <- c("sexual", "racist", "ill")
funnel_terms <- paste0("\\b", funnel_terms, "\\b")
output_1 <- sapply(seq_len(length(funnel_terms)), function (z) {
  sum(sapply(sapply(gregexpr(funnel_terms[z], df$text), function (x) {
    if (x[1] == -1) {
      y <- NULL
    } else {
      y <- x
    }
    y
  }), length))
})
names(output_1) <- original_funnel_terms
output_2 <- paste(names(output), " - ", as.character(output), sep = "")
cat(output_2, sep = "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample data set similar to yours with the following code:

```
sample <- tribble(~funnel_term, "['Sexual']", "['Islam', 'Religion']", "['Sexual', 'Islam']")
```

Which gives you a data frame that looks like this:

```
  funnel_term          
  <chr>                
1 ['Sexual']           
2 ['Islam', 'Religion']
3 ['Sexual', 'Islam']
```

You can get rid of the brackets and single quotes and then separate the rows so that **each item in the list becomes it's own row**

```
sample.1 <- sample %>% mutate(funnel_term_new = gsub("\\[|\\]|\'", "", funnel_term)) %>% separate_rows(funnel_term_new, sep = ", ")
```

Which gives you a data frame that looks like this:

```
  funnel_term           funnel_term_new
  <chr>                 <chr>          
1 ['Sexual']            Sexual         
2 ['Islam', 'Religion'] Islam          
3 ['Islam', 'Religion'] Religion       
4 ['Sexual', 'Islam']   Sexual         
5 ['Sexual', 'Islam']   Islam
```

Now that you have all of the funnel terms into their own row, you can use simple `dplyr` functions to get the **count of each unique funnel_term**:

```
sample.final <- sample.1 %>% group_by(funnel_term_new) %>% summarise(n = n())
  funnel_term_new     n
  <chr>           <int>
1 Islam               2
2 Religion            1
3 Sexual              2
```

Comment: Thanks, though I want it to count Islam 4 times for example..

Comment: In the example data frame it’s only in there twice. The df that has it 4 times is just a part of the processing to get the final count